# How to return a populated growable Hashmap in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, hashmap

This is my Java code :

```
package utils;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import static com.app.core.AcType.*;
import static java.time.LocalDate.parse;


import com.app.core.BankAccount;

public interface CollectionUtils {
//add a static method to return fixed size populated list of bank accounts
    static List<BankAccount> populateAcctList() {
        return Arrays.asList(new BankAccount(10, "abc1", SAVING, 10000, parse("2020-01-19")),
                new BankAccount(100, "abc4", FD, 200000, parse("2019-01-19")),
                new BankAccount(34, "abc3", CURRENT, 5000, parse("2010-11-29")),
                new BankAccount(15, "abc6", SAVING, 12000, parse("2011-06-23")),
                new BankAccount(64, "abc8", SAVING, 9000, parse("2020-01-19")),
                new BankAccount(49, "abc2", DMAT, 13000, parse("2020-01-19"))
                );
    }
    //add a method to ret a populated growable hashmap from above sample data ??????
    
    static HashMap<String, BankAccount> populateAccountHashMap(){
        return 
    }
}
```

I have added a `static` method to return a fixed size populated list of bank accounts!
Now, I want to add a `static` method to return a populated growable HashMap from the same data! I'm not able to figure out how to do it?

Comment: A `Map` maps between pairs of data.  You have only one here, the `BankAccount`.  How do you want to use the `HashMap`?

Comment: You have a list of `BankAccounts` here.  So  assuming each bank account is a value in the map, what would be the keys?  And are the keys part of the account or a separate piece of information(String, int, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have a `List<BankAccount>` named `accounts` you can do it like this.

```
Map<String, BankAccount> map = 
                    accounts.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(BankAccount::getAccountName, acct->acct));
```

This presumes the name is the second element (or some other String) in your bank account instance and has the shown getter.  If you want the key to be something else,  adjust accordingly.  Note that this particular solution assumes a one-to-one mapping of keys and BankAccounts.  If you have duplicate keys (i.e in this case, multiple accounts per name) it will throw an exception.  Then you can do it like this where each name will refer to a list of liked named accounts.

```
Map<String,List<BankAccount>> map =  accounts.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(BankAccount::getAccountName));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got my Answer!

```
//add a method to ret a populated growable hashmap from above sample data ??????
    
    static HashMap<Integer, BankAccount> populateAccountHashMap(){
        HashMap<Integer, BankAccount> temp = new HashMap<Integer, BankAccount>();
        temp.put(10, new BankAccount(10, "abc1", SAVING, 10000, parse("2020-01-19")));
        temp.put(100, new BankAccount(100, "abc4", FD, 200000, parse("2019-01-19")));
        temp.put(34, new BankAccount(34, "abc3", CURRENT, 5000, parse("2010-11-29")));
        temp.put(15, new BankAccount(15, "abc6", SAVING, 12000, parse("2011-06-23")));
        temp.put(64, new BankAccount(64, "abc8", SAVING, 9000, parse("2020-01-19")));
        temp.put(49, new BankAccount(49, "abc2", DMAT, 13000, parse("2020-01-19")));
        return temp;
    }
```

It is verified!

Comment: Why would you do it that way? You already have the data in a list. So why not use the list to populate the HashMap? Otherwise, if you make changes to the data, you need to make them in two locations instead of one.  And just so you are aware, you are making new instances of the BankAccount.  So if you change one in one data structure, that change won't be reflected in another.  This could be problematic when altering account balances.  Then again, maybe that's what you want.

Answer (score -2):

When you use Java 9+, then `Map.of()` is useful.

**EDIT**

I fixed my example.
Note that `Map.of()` returns an immutable map, so you need to wrap it to make it growable.

```
  Map<String, BankAccount> map = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
    "abc1", new BankAccount(10, "abc1", SAVING, 10000, parse("2020-01-19")),
    "abc4", new BankAccount(100, "abc4", FD, 200000, parse("2019-01-19"))
  ));
```

Comment: Since `Map.of` is an immutable map, it is not very growable.  You need to pass the `Map.of` map as an argument to a map implementation.  E.g. `new HashMap<>(Map.of(....));`

Comment: @wjs   You are right... I fixed my example.